# video sequence editor- how to render video with reversed picture order?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

How can I reverse the picture-order (like the rendered video plays from end to beggining) in VSE? is there a quicker way than to render it as individual pictures and renameing them so that the order switches?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Select your strip and on the filter tab select **Backwards**

[image]

Comment: In 3.2, it's now in the section called _Video_ (rather than _Filter_ as shown in the older version in the answer) and is now called _Reverse Frames_ (rather than _Backwards_).